# Angular2 How get user information using POST request and utilize them

Tags: angular, http, authentication

Hi I am front developer so I don't know the codes of backend.

Right now, I am using POST request to get user information from the server and I've successfully gotten user data in json object (at least I think) but for some reasons, I can't use this json data.

Maybe I am getting the data incorrectly or I forgot some codes to add but I don't know how to fix this problem.

These are the codes.

Model

```
export interface User {
birthday: number;
email:string;
gender:string;
memberType: string;
name: string;
phone: string;
profilePicture: string;
uid:string;
}
```

Login Service

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Http, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
    import { RequestMethod, RequestOptions, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    import { User } from '../../model/auth_user';

    import { environment } from '../../index/baseUrl';

   @Injectable()
   export class AuthenticationService {
       constructor(private http: Http, private router: Router) { }

       login(email: string, password: string) {
    const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'post');
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    headers.append("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");

    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    let body = new URLSearchParams();
    body.set('email', email);
    body.set('password', password);

    return this.http.post(`${environment.baseurl}` + '/api/member/login', body, options)
        .map((response: Response) => {
            let user = response.json();
            if (user && user.token) {
                localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
            }
        });
       }

       logout() {
    // remove user from local storage to log user out
    localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');

       }
   }
```

Login component

```
    export class LoginPageComponent implements OnInit {

        constructor(private location: Location,
            private route: ActivatedRoute,
            private router: Router,
            private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
            private alertService: AlertService) {
             }

        model: any = {};
        loading = false;
        returnUrl: string;

        error = '';

        ngOnInit() {
            // reset login status
            this.authenticationService.logout();

            // get return url from route parameters or default to '/'
            this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['main'] || '/';
        }

            login() {
        this.loading = true;
        this.authenticationService.login(this.model.email, this.model.password)
            .subscribe(
            data => {
                this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
            },
            error => {
                this.error = "Wrong Id or Password"; <- this doesn't appear even though the error spits 404 I don't know why.. :(
                this.loading = false;
            });
    }


    backClicked() {
        this.location.back();
    }
  }
```

Login html template

```
    <form name="form" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && login()" #f="ngForm" novalidate>
        <div id="main-container">
            <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': f.submitted && !email.valid }">
                <label for="email">email</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email"     [(ngModel)]="model.email" #email="ngModel" required />
        <div *ngIf="f.submitted && !email.valid" class="help-block">Please type in your e-mail</div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': f.submitted && !password.valid }">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" 
        [(ngModel)]="model.password" #password="ngModel" required />
        <div *ngIf="f.submitted && !password.valid" class="help-block">Please type in password.</div>

        <br>

    </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <button [disabled]="loading" class="btn btn-primary" id="button3">Login</button>
         <img *ngIf="loading" src="data:image/gif;base64,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" />
        </div>

        <div *ngIf="error" class="alert alert-danger">{{error}}</div>
           </div>

       </form>
```

Here, I also want if user types in wrong id or pw, and if the server spits 404 error, I want to display wrong id or password but my method is not working.

Home component

```
export class MainComponent {

  public toggled(open: boolean): void {
    console.log('Dropdown is now: ', open);
  }

  onClick() {

  }

  currentUser: User;

  items: Object[] = [];

  constructor(private authguard: AuthGuard) {
    this.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
  }

}
```

And now I want to get currentUser's name and memberType but it's not working!
Home component html template

```
<p class="drpdown3" role="menuitem"> Welcome! {{currentUser.name}}{{currentUser.memberType | type_transform}}</p>
```

this isn't working..

What I am doing wrong?

I am referring to this website : http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/09/29/angular-2-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial

Comment: please post the console error

Comment: in your  authentication service, you are using the .map() method of the observable but not returning anything at the end of the map, so nothing will get passed through it... probably should be something like map(res => {... return user})